# Bootstrap 4. Text in block is moved outside it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, google-chrome-devtools, adaptive-design

[The image when browser is collapsed to minimal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHeIv.png)

[Original site view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTiKA.png)

[Site from mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QWNf.png)

When site is collapsed, the text is going outside the block's frames. The same is happening when the mobile view is turned on at DevTools.

For developing I used Bootstrap 4.

Text needs to go on new line in block frames, instead it going out of it. overflow-wrap does not change anything.

```
 HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <title>Визитная карточка</title>
</head>
<body class="setting-body">

<div class="head">
    <h1>Домашнее задание</h1>
</div>

<div class="copy-jumbotron jumbotron ">
    <div class="row parent">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 setting-div-for-image">
            <div>
                <img class="setting-image" src="Resources/Avatar.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 setting-information">
            <h2>Королев Максим Евгеньевич</h2>
            <p>Студент с многопрофильного колледжа ТИУ, желающий научиться программировать</p>
            <p>Ссылки на социальные <wbr /> сети:</p>
            <div>
                <div class="links">
                    <div class="links">
                        <a class=" links-iteems text-links" target="_blank" href="https://github.com/MaxZmoZg">
                            <img class="img-links" src="Resources/Git-Icon-Black.png" />
                            <p class="paragraph">GitHub</p>
                        </a>
                        <a class="links-iteems text-links" target="_blank" href="https://vk.com/max_koroliov">
                            <img class="img-links" src="Resources/Vklogo.png" />
                            <p class="paragraph">Вконтакте</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    flex-direction: row;

}   

.setting-image{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:90px;
    align-content:center;
}
.setting-div-for-image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.setting-information{
    width:100% !important;
     overflow-wrap: break-word;

}

.links {
    display: flex;

}
.links-iteems {
    display: flex;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.img-links{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    flex:auto;

}

.text-links {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.text-links:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1f8ac8;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.paragraph {
    display:flex;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.copy-jumbotron {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: #fcfafa !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 1px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 1px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 1px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
 overflow-wrap: break-word;

}
.head{
    font-size:25px;
}

.setting-body{
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on JSFiddle and on my own system and it seems to be working fine.
This is possibly down to Operating system + browser combination differences. Could you please add the OS and Browser you are seeing this issue for? Then we can try to replicate the issue :)

[image: ScreenSizeOfBootstrapBoxNotOverflowing]